# Does Outlook.com (office online) offer the Destkop Email Alert/Notification feature?

Tags: outlook.com, office-live

I would like my outlook.com account to display a notification/alert when new e-mails arrive, just as in the regular outlook.

Did anyone find out if this feature is available ?
I tried chrome extensions, messing with outlook.com's options, to no avail.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am accessing outlook.com via a remote desktop connection, with Windows Server 2008 R2. Why do you ask ? I am talking about office's live (online) version.

Comment: If you were using Windows 8 (or later), I'd suggest pointing the mail app at your outlook.com account, then you'd get toast notifications of new mail, and meeting reminders.